# How to interpret coordinates using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

**We got an file called coords.txt where tons of coordinates are listed. We'd like to read them line by line and do something with them, but we need to set x, y and z first.**

**coords.txt:**

```
0, 0, 0
1, 1, 1
232, 434, 434
644, 322, 112
```

**shell.sh** **EDIT:**

```
coord_reader='^[0-9], [0-9], [0-9]'
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo $line
    if [[ $line =~ $coord_reader ]]; then

        x=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        y=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        z=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        echo "x is $x, y is $y, z is $z"
else
echo "wrong"
fi

done < "$1"
```

We start it using `bash shell.sh coords.txt`

Looks like there is an issue in the **coord_reader**, I get just an result for x.

*I am new to stackoverflow, feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is only matching single-digit numbers, and you aren't using capture groups. (As an aside, make sure `coords.txt` properly ends with a newline, so that you don't need the `|| [[ -n $line ]]` hack in your `while` loop.)

```
coord_reader='^([0-9]+), ([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)$'
```

Comment: Thx for the `|| [[ -n $line ]]` info btw :) I'll check it out!

Comment: Well, if I get just some less coordinates in file it works, but with 5000+ entries it doesn't work :/ How to fix that?

Comment: Nothing about this code suggests an upper limit on the number of lines it can handle. Performance will be slow, but it should still work.

Comment: I included an "else" if it's not the correct regular expression. If there are less entries it works, but like I said 5000+ it tells me "wrong", which means to match.

Comment: What is the value of `$line` when it outputs `wrong`?

Comment: $line still looks like it should, e.g. `100, 101, 100`.

Comment: Looks can be deceiving. What does `printf '%s' "$line" | od` produce?

Comment: E.g. `0000000 034061 026067 034440 026071 032040 030067 000015
0000015
187, 99, 470
wrong
` - just added it after the normal output of $line.

Comment: The `000015` at the end of the octal output indicates that the current line ends with a carriage return; at some point, your file starts to use DOS line endings, which need to be removed. (I suspect your file was created by concatenating several separate files into one?)

Comment: Short answer: your code is fine; your input file is not a proper POSIX text file, which `bash` assumes.

Comment: Got it! `tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file`- Thx for ur big help!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '$0 ~ /^([[:digit:]]+),[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+),[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+).*$/ { print "x="$1" y="$2" z="$3 }' coords.txt
```

Another alternative is awk. We pattern match for the regular expression. I notice that there is also a space in before the comma (not sure if this is intentional) If the pattern matches, then print out the string with x=,y=,z= using the relative positioned strings separated using the comma.